# Algebraic K-theory of compositum of fields $K_2(F.M)$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $F$ and $E$ be two subfields of a fixed field $K$, then the compositum $F.E$ is just $F(E)=E(F)$.

Let  $K_2$ be the second Milnor algebraic K-group.

I ma asking if we can express (or lift ) elements   of $K_2(F.E)$ in  terms of those in $K_2(F)$ and  $K_2(E)$?

If not in general. Are there specific cases for which this holds?